# How does the bottom resistor in feedback resistive divider impact noise sensitivity?

Tags: operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply, noise, buck, voltage-divider

***What does this line (underlined) mean?***

Does the datasheet imply the loading effect due to error amplifier?

[image]
[MPS datasheet](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP28257/document_id/553)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/Basic-Linear-Design/Chapter12.pdf) answers the question
[image]

Comment: Noise pick usually takes place via stray capacitance. In the real world every object is connected to any other object by an individual stray capacitance. This can be small, if the two objects are small and/or far away from each other, or it can be large, if the objects are large and/or close to each other.
Inductive noise coupling happens whenever conductors form a loop and a magnetic field (from a mains transformer, e.g.) is penetrating this loop area. Then, a voltage is induced in this loop and a current will flow in this loop which causes voltage drops across impedances in this loop.

Answer (score 9):

The higher the impedance of a node, the more susceptible the node is to induced noise.  Lower impedance results in a higher "load" on the noise source, reducing the voltage coupled in.

Comment: And (as the context suggests this is in a SMPS) there is highly likely to be a noise source nearby.

Answer (score 5):

If your circuit has for example capacitive coupling between the SW node and the FB node, the same capacitive coupling impedance has less effect to the FB node if R2 impedance is low (e.g. 5k) than if R2 impedance is high (e.g. 50k).

Answer (score 3):

> ***What does this line (underlined) mean?***

Too large is like 1M scope probe. Next you are near one a scope, touch the tip without grounding yourself report back the Vac-pp. Even more with a 10:1 probe. There are inductive loop and capacitive ingress issues with high impedance noise pickup.

> Does the datasheet imply the loading effect due to error amplifier?

NO. The FB input uses an internal precision  constant voltage to compare the ratio of the output. This regulates by amplifying towards nulling this error like a differential Amp.